# Get element from JSON string in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

```
@foreach (var fieldset in Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<ArchetypeModel>("MainMenuDT"))
{
    <li>@fieldset.GetValue("linkObj")</li> 
}
```

this outputs:

```
[  
   {  
      "caption":"gjhg",
      "link":"http://localhost:2081/",
      "newWindow":false,
      "edit":false,
      "isInternal":false,
      "type":"external",
      "title":"gjhg"
   }
]
```

How can I get the value of the linkObj.link element from the JSON string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what `Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<ArchetypeModel>("MainMenuDT")` returns, but it's really easy parsing json's  using `JSON.net`:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public string caption {get;set;}
  public string link {get;set;}
  public bool newWindow {get;set;}
  public bool edit {get;set;}
  public bool isInternal {get;set;}
  public string type{get;set;}
  public string title{get;set;}
}

List<MyObject> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(json); // json is a string
if(obj.Count > 0)
{
   string link = obj[0].link;
}
```